# Lagrange interpolation formula question

Tags: lagrange-interpolation

Find the number of values of $x$ satisfying the relation
$$
\alpha_1^3 \left( \frac{\prod_{i=2}^n (x - \alpha_i)}{\prod_{i=2}^n (\alpha_1 - \alpha_i)} \right) + \sum_{j=2}^{n-1} \left( \left( \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{j-1}(x-\alpha_i)\prod_{i=j+1}^n(x-\alpha_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^{j-1}(\alpha_j - \alpha_i) \prod_{i=j+1}^n(\alpha_j - \alpha_i) } \right) \alpha_j^3 \right) + \left( \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(x-\alpha_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(\alpha_n - \alpha_i)} \right)\alpha_n^3 - x^3 = 0
$$
where $n \geq 5$

Comment: I do not see any inequality here, except for "$n\ge5$".

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128988/find-the-number-of-values-of-x-satisfying-the-relation) was already asked Feb 27 by [saket kumar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/631974/saket-kumar) (the only difference is a few added words from the beginning of my answer). It was answered Feb 28 by [Ehsaan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3129709/71850)  (0 upvotes), Mar 4 by [me](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3134390/71850) (3 upvotes & bounty), and Mar 8 by  [Yuri Negometyanov](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3140345/71850) (0 upvotes).

Comment: Mar 13 it was closed as unclear what you're asking by [GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/290189/gnusupporter-8964%e6%b0%91%e4%b8%bb%e5%a5%b3%e7%a5%9e-%e5%9c%b0%e4%b8%8b%e6%95%99%e6%9c%83), [Parcly Taxel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357390/parcly-taxel), [Xander Henderson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/468350/xander-henderson), [Saad](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/302797/saad), and [user21820](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21820/user21820).

Comment: Mar 16 it was deleted by [Saad](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/302797/saad), [José Carlos Santos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/446262/jos%c3%a9-carlos-santos), and [Parcly Taxel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357390/parcly-taxel).

Answer (score 3):

In your notation, $p(x)$ is a Lagrange interpolation of degree $n-1$, hence $q(x)$ is of degree $n-1 > 3$. Therefore, if $q(x)$ is not the zero polynomial, it can have **at most** $n-1$ roots for $q(x) = 0$.

On the other hand, because $p(\alpha_i) = \alpha_i^3$, you already know that $$\{\alpha_i\mid i = 1,2, \dots, n\}$$ are all roots of $q(x)$. Hence, *if $\alpha_i$'s are all distinct*, there are **at least** $n$ roots for $q(x)$.

Therefore, $q(x)$ has more roots than its degree, ergo $q(x) = 0$ and there are infinite number of roots.

Comment: But the answer of the this question is there is infinite number of roots

Comment: For distinct $i$ and $j$, $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$ are  distinct because we have $\alpha_j-\alpha_i$ in a denominator.

Comment: unless $p(x)=q(x)$, then there are more than $n$ roots.

Answer (score 1):

Below I copied the relevant part of my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3134390/71850) to the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128988/find-the-number-of-values-of-x-satisfying-the-relation).

> It is easy to see that $p(x)$ is the [interpolation polynomial in the Lagrange form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) of a function $x^3$. That is, $p(x)=x^3$ when $x=\alpha_i$ for each $i$. Since $q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ which has at least $n$ roots $\alpha_i$, $q(x)$ is the zero polynomial. That is, the initial equality holds for each $x\in\Bbb C$.

If you wish, I can provide for you other answers from this deleted thread.

Comment: Give me detail solution of this question plz

Comment: @AbhishekKumar The provided solution is already detailed. Which additional details do you need or which issues do you need to clarify? Also, do you need other answers from the deleted thread?

Answer (score 1):

$$\alpha_1^3 \left( \frac{\prod_{i=2}^n (x - \alpha_i)}{\prod_{i=2}^n (\alpha_1 - \alpha_i)} \right) + \sum_{j=2}^{n-1} \left( \left( \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{j-1}(x-\alpha_i)\prod_{i=j+1}^n(x-\alpha_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^{j-1}(\alpha_j - \alpha_i) \prod_{i=j+1}^n(\alpha_j - \alpha_i) } \right) \alpha_j^3 \right) + \left( \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(x-\alpha_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(\alpha_n - \alpha_i)} \right)\alpha_n^3 =x^3$$

$$\alpha_1^3 \left( \frac{(x - \alpha_2)(x - \alpha_3)......(x - \alpha_n)}{(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)(\alpha_1 - \alpha_3)......(\alpha_1 - \alpha_n)} \right) +\alpha_2^3 \left( \frac{(x - \alpha_1)(x - \alpha_3)......(x - \alpha_n)}{(\alpha_2 - \alpha_1)(\alpha_2 - \alpha_3)......(\alpha_2 - \alpha_n)} \right) +\alpha_3^3 \left( \frac{(x - \alpha_1)(x - \alpha_2)......(x - \alpha_n)}{(\alpha_3 - \alpha_1)(\alpha_3 - \alpha_2)......(\alpha_2 - \alpha_n)} \right) +.........+........+\alpha_n^3 \left( \frac{(x - \alpha_1)(x - \alpha_2)....(x - \alpha_{n-1})}{(\alpha_n - \alpha_1)(\alpha_n - \alpha_2)....(\alpha_n - \alpha_{n-1})} \right)=x^3$$
Given equation has degree $n-1$ which satisfy $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,........\alpha_n$ so it become a identity.
Hence, it has infinity many solution.